# How to convert any numeric string value in int?

Tags: python, converters

I would like to convert either `0x123`, `012` or `36#foo` into an integer.

To do so, I wrote this:

```
def str2int(s):
    if re.findall('(?i)^0x',s):
        return int(s, 16)
    if re.findall('^(?i)0',s):
        return int(s, 8)
    m = re.findall('(?i)^(\d+)\#([0-9a-z]+)',s)
    if m:
        return int(m[0][1], m[0][0])
    raise AssertionError, 'Unknown value'
```

I feel it is a bit complicated. Is there any builtin method?

Comment: I think if you want to interpret arbitrary bases, your solution is the best you’ll find for this. There is no built-in way for this because `base#number` is not a built-in supported expression format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("0x123")
291
>>> ast.literal_eval("012")
10
>>> ast.literal_eval("36#foo")
36
```

However, note that `literal_eval("012")` will only work in 2.7 and lower because 3.x no longer supports that style of octal literal. But this will work:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("0o12")
10
```

Comment: It does not work. `echo $(( 36#foo ))` gives `20328` not `36`

Comment: Oh. In that case, there's no built-in that does that.

Comment: Well, I guess nobody will use it anymore. It is just fun :)

Comment: @nowox How does `'echo $(( 36#foo ))'` give you `20328`? Also how would you expect that to be parsed? It’s not even following any pattern (and it’s so very different than your examples in the question).

Comment: That's base 36. `int('foo', 36)` -> 20328.

Answer (score 2):

Solution without regular expressions:

```
def convert (s):
    if s.lower().startswith('0x'):
        s = '16#' + s[2:]
    elif s.startswith('0'):
        s = '8#' + s[1:]
    elif '#' not in s:
        s = '10#' + s
    base, num = s.split('#', 1)
    return int(num, int(base))
```

```
>>> testcases = [('0x123', 291), ('012', 10), ('36#foo', 20328)]
>>> for s, n in testcases:
        print(s, n, n == convert(s))

0x123 291 True
012 10 True
36#foo 20328 True
```

Comment: This is a good answer -- while you are at it maybe you could tweak it to handle binary literals to make it even more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

`int` will do, when you pass `0` as second argument:

```
   int('0x123', 0)
=> 291
   int('0o12', 0)
=> 10
```

If you want to support comments, `str.partition` is the simplest way I can think about:

```
   int('36#foo'.partition('#')[0], 0)
=> 36
```